# pureftpd virtual user doesn't work with a concrete "base" user

Tags: arch-linux, ftp

Hello I want a virtual ftp user to upload web stuff so I want one using http user and webgroup (I group I created).

So I did:

```
pure-pw useradd webftp -u http -g webgroup -d /srv/http
pure-pw mkdb
```

And restarted the daemon.

When I try to log in it says:

```
530 Sorry, but I can't trust you
```

I created a ftpuser as the official guide says:

```
useradd -g ftpgroup -d /dev/null -s /etc ftpuser
```

and I Did:

```
pure-pw useradd webftp -u ftpuser -g webgroup -d /srv/http
pure-pw mkdb
```

Now It works but I want http to be the user so there is something that pure-pw doesn't like about http user:

```
ftpuser:x:1001:1001::/dev/null:/etc
http:x:33:33:http:/srv/http:/bin/false
```

ftpuser have no directory, http user have /srv/http and http user have no shell.

What exactly is making this trouble? And... I'm not sure if I change something about the user and chorokee will cry or something (I think that the user was created that way for a reason).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the records. The problem was that pureftpd have a "MinUID" variable and it doesn't allow an user of UID < 100 to log in.

Comment: I have this error, but my MinUID is fine, user is 504, MinUID is 500 .. trying to use Pam Auth which used to work. I was tailed `/var/log/messages` and realized I my uploadscript was not starting even though I had `CallUploadScript yes`. That seemed to fix the problem. The uploadscript has to be started before pure-ftpd.